# Geoserver out of memory

Tags: geoserver, wms

I have some memory problems with my Geoserver.

I am currently running Geoserver 2.5.2 (installed from Windows Service Installer) on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

When I launch the service (Start Geoserver) I see Java consumes about 174MB of memory. When I request WMSLayers, I see the memory increases each time with each request to reach 1,109GB but it never decreases. So after a while it stops working.

WMSLayers are used to render a PNG file (width 6520, height 4078, bit depth 32, size 1.2KB) stored in the same server as the Geoserver is installed.

In the wrapper.conf files, the maximum java heap was 512 MB so i have changed it to 1024 MB yet i still get the problem.

```
Error in the geoserver log: 
*2015-12-03 09:32:34,869 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2015-12-03 09:32:34,869 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Unable to renderer this raster, no workaround found
2015-12-03 09:32:34,870 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Raster rendered
2015-12-03 09:32:34,870 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Rendering Raster CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.GridCoverageWrapper["mosaic-1440", GeneralEnvelope[(-127.327144225, 21.27408544), (-49.75003262499999, 57.99455878)], DefaultGeographicCRS["WGS 84"]]
?   CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.WrappedSampleDimension([])
?   CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.WrappedSampleDimension([])
?   CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.WrappedSampleDimension([])
?   CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.WrappedSampleDimension([])
? Image=RenderedOp["ImageRead"]

2015-12-03 09:32:34,870 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Drawing coverage CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.GridCoverageWrapper["mosaic-1440", GeneralEnvelope[(-127.327144225, 21.27408544), (-49.75003262499999, 57.99455878)], DefaultGeographicCRS["WGS 84"]]
?   CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.WrappedSampleDimension([])
?   CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.WrappedSampleDimension([])
?   CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.WrappedSampleDimension([])
?   CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.WrappedSampleDimension([])
? Image=RenderedOp["ImageRead"]

2015-12-03 09:32:34,870 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Drawing coverage CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.GridCoverageWrapper["mosaic-1440", GeneralEnvelope[(-127.327144225, 21.27408544), (-49.75003262499999, 57.99455878)], DefaultGeographicCRS["WGS 84"]]
?   CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.WrappedSampleDimension([])
?   CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.WrappedSampleDimension([])
?   CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.WrappedSampleDimension([])
?   CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.WrappedSampleDimension([])
? Image=RenderedOp["ImageRead"]

2015-12-03 09:32:34,871 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Transforming coverage envelope with transform INVERSE_MT[PARAM_MT["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0]]]
2015-12-03 09:32:34,871 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Using interpolation javax.media.jai.InterpolationNearest@67a7e2
2015-12-03 09:32:34,872 DEBUG [org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform] - Optimizing the warp into an affine transformation: AffineTransform[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
2015-12-03 09:32:34,876 TRACE [org.geotools.resources] - Loaded resources for English from bundle "org.geotools.resources.i18n".
2015-12-03 09:32:34,876 DEBUG [org.geotools.coverage.processing] - Resampled coverage "mosaic-1440" from coordinate system "WGS 84" (for an image of size 56×27) to coordinate system "WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator" (image size 56×27). JAI operation is "Warp" with "Nearest" interpolation on geophysics pixels values. Background value is (0, 0, 0, 0).
2015-12-03 09:32:34,876 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Reprojecting to crs PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]], 
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
2015-12-03 09:32:34,876 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Raster Symbolizer 
2015-12-03 09:32:34,896 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Raster Symbolizer 
2015-12-03 09:32:34,897 TRACE [org.geotools.resources] - Loaded resources for <default> from bundle "org.geotools.renderer.i18n".
2015-12-03 09:33:01,688 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2015-12-03 09:33:01,689 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Unable to renderer this raster, no workaround found
2015-12-03 09:33:01,689 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Raster rendered
2015-12-03 09:33:01,689 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Style cache hit ratio: NaN , hits 0, requests 0
2015-12-03 09:33:01,689 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: This requested used more time than allowed and has been forcefully stopped. Max rendering time is 60.0s
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:501)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:251)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:123)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:509)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:253)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:124)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor266.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:61)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:54)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:54)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.getMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor225.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:790)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:27)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:75)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450)*
```

## NB: If i did the same request when i restart Geoserver, it will only take 2 seconds.

Comment: That is a timeout message not an error. Please add the log file (debug level) of the actual request being made, a note of what the layer you are trying to render is and where it is stored.

Comment: Sorry @iant but how to get the debug level? Im using wms layers to render a shape file in the same server as the geoserver

Comment: Go to Global settings - Logging profile. Geotools developer profile is probably best for your case. I suppose you have big shapefiles and you are requesting a large area -> lots of vectors to handle for rendering the image.

Comment: goto the global settings and change the logging level there

Comment: Thanks @user30184 , i have edited my question with the geotools developer logger. I found out that i'm using a png file (6520*4078) as a wmslayer not a shapefile. sorry

Comment: Png is the worst file format of all for servers because it must be decompressed totally before server can do anything for it. Convert it into tiled tiff using LZW, deflate, or jpeg compression depending on the nature of the png. Jpeg for aerial images, LZW or deflate for maps. Create also overview layers. You will find instructions from the web.

Comment: @user30184 i will try your suggestion. Do you think really using tiff instead png will improve geoserver performance with concurrent requests? Doing more than 10 simultaneous wms requests will not cause memory error again? if yes whats the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: You will notice the difference, big png files are not for servers. If having tiled tiffs is not enough, consider tiling with GeoWebCache.

Comment: @iant Thanks , i have edited my question with the geotools developer logger

Comment: http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html

Comment: I tested 50 MB PNG's in production (with saving to cache). With good setting Geoserver can handle pressure made by few users... Today I think better are GeoTiff's or JPEG2000 (can be used after installing plugin).

Comment: @DavidK witch plugin should be installed with GeoTiff files?

Comment: @mhd geotiff should work by default I think (if you have problems it's probably made by too "liberal" rules about what can be saved inside file headers - use http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html ); JPEG2000 is installed with plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Java Heap space isn't the only important parameter you have to set when working with rasters. I had to deal with caching of many layers inside my Geoserver and it was still crashing until I set these parameters to my "bin/startup.bat" file (Xms, Xmx, MaxPermSize):

`:run if "%JAVA_OPTS%" == "" (set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx6144m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m")`

Take a look here ([Advanced Production GeoServer configuration](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adv_gsconfig/gsproduction.html)) for more informations. I believe this can help you.